# My WCF application uses 2 way certificate message encryption - does it still need SSL?

Tags: encryption, certificates, wcf

I have a WCF service configured to use two-way certificate authentication on the messages.

The server is also locked down through a firewall to only allow traffic from a single IP:Port that the client is also using.

Is SSL for the transport layer still a good idea, or overkill?

Answer (score 2):

In a word: yes.

All message encryption does is make part of the communication confidential. SSL makes sure you're talking to the right server and makes sure nobody listening in can figure out who you're talking to.